# Check values inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array

```
 A[0]=array {
    title="a";
    filename="1.jpg"
    }
 A[1]=array {
    title="a";
    filename="2.jpg"
    }
```

Now my out put like

```
A
1.jpg
A
2.jpg
```

I wish an output like

```
A
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

So i tried

```
<?php 
$name='';
foreach($items as $item){
    if ( $item['title'] =$name) {
        $item['name']['file']=$item['filename']
    }
}
?>
```

Bad luck its not working.please help me

Comment: Coding is never based on Luck

Comment: Your array looks odd... Are you sure it's not an object?

Comment: Bad logic* is not working

Comment: Look up when to use `=` and when to use `==` HINT: tests use `==`

Comment: _Small Point_ This code is not OUTPUTTING anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-arrange array first and then printout data from it:

```
<?php 

$finalArray = [];

foreach($items as $item){
    $finalArray[$item['title']]['filename'][] = $item['filename']; 
}

foreach($finalArray as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($value['filename'] as $val){
        echo $val.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/oklHW

Note:- if your initial array is an stdClass object array then do like below:-

```
$finalArray = [];

foreach($items as $item){
    $finalArray[$item->title]['filename'][] = $item->filename; 
}

foreach($finalArray as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($value['filename'] as $val){
        echo $val.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/DWrn1